# remove empty space after new line in a string mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field called "system" in my database which looks like this

system field;

```
registration    //This field is part of a table called "system_owner" 
elearning       //all three value is in one string which each contains "\n"
payment
```

When I removed the "elearning" with this SQL statement;

```
$SQL = "UPDATE system_owner SET system=REPLACE(system,'elearning','')
```

The system field became like this;

```
registration

payment
```

My problem is how do I remove the empty space between "registration" and "payment"?
What SQL statement should I use?

The output of the field that I want

```
registration
payment
```

Comment: This is a common problem for tables not adhering to the [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). It's usually hard to work with such fields in SQL so a common way is to do all the work in the application code instead. Here's an example on how to do it in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11079123/238978

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you try:

```
$SQL = "UPDATE system_owner SET system=REPLACE(system,'elearning\n','')
```

Comment: It works but when I try to display it into a textarea box, there's still empty space between them. I don't know why but in the database, the data looks exactly what I wanted. What went wrong?

Comment: Can you show how you are displaying in textarea? May be its something that you are doing while displaying in the textarea.

Comment: <textarea name="rSistem" id="own" rows="6" cols="30" style="resize: none;" >'.$system.'</textarea>

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking too much but can you try it out? save something like mine from a textarea into database and edit the data. Then display it again into the textarea. Maybe you know what went wrong that way.